# CakePHP Making Child Models for different types of Comments

Tags: cakephp, inheritance, model, cakephp-1.2

I have a `Comment` Model that I am using to store comments for both `Goal`s and `Note`s.

The current implementation has a `GoalComment` Model and a `NoteComment` Model, each of which `extends Comment`, and the `Comment`'s `beforeFind` does the following:

```
$queryData['conditions'][$this->name . '.' . $this->__type_field] = $this->name;
```

which basically sets the `type` field of the `Comment` Model to either `GoalComment` or `NoteComment`, depending on which of those classes is performing a `find`.

This implementation has worked up until now, where I want to delete comments. Below is the Model association for Comments in Goals:

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'GoalComment',
        'foreignKey' => 'object_id'
    )
);
```

And in my beforeDelete, where I want to remove all comments associated with the goal, I have:

```
$this->Comment->deleteAll(array('object_id' => $this->id));
```

But I get the following SQL error:

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'GoalComment.type' in 'where clause' [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 525]
Query: SELECT `Comment`.`id` FROM `comments` AS `Comment` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `Poster` ON (`Comment`.`poster_id` = `Poster`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `goals` AS `Goal` ON (`Comment`.`object_id` = `Goal`.`id`)  
WHERE `object_id` = 52 AND `GoalComment`.`type` = 'GoalComment'
```

This is happening because of the `beforeFind` action I described before, which adds the `GoalComment.type = 'GoalComment'`. This has made me rethink the whole approach to the situation.

So my **question** is how should this relationship be re-implemented? My best idea is to scrap the `beforeFind` in `Comment` and simply remake the `$hasMany` relationship to be:

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'object_id',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.type = "GoalComment"')
    )
);
```

This would extract all of the thinking from the `Comment` Model, and it just seems more natural to me.

**Do you have an idea for a better implementation, or should I go with the one above?** Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're correct in realizing that you've been over-thinking the associations.

The "normal" way for this type of relationship is to simply use the fields `model` and `foreign_key` in your comments table.

```
//Comment model
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Goal' => array(
        'className' => 'Goal',
        'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.model' => 'Goal')
    ,
    'Note' => array(
        'className' => 'Note',
        'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.model' => 'Note')
    )
);

//Goal model
public $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.model' => 'Goal')
    )
);

//Note model
public $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.model' => 'Note')
    )
);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That's what I was thinking, minus the $belong**s**To. However, this problem was not something I started. That's why this is extra hard haha! Fixing other people's code is always an adventure.

Comment: Glad to help.  And I completely understand about the "fun" of working with someone else's code.

Comment: There exist certain strange definitions of [fun](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Losing).